# Under what condition a set of $\{0,1\}$-sequences will contain two sequences having the same entries in at least $k$ positions

Tags: combinatorics, information-theory, coding-theory

I have a set $S$ of sequences of zeros and ones (the sequence length is $2^n-1$). I need to know if there is a condition on the number of elements of $S$ which will imply the existence of two sequences in $S$ having an intersection of at least $k$ elements. (They have the same entries in at least $k$ positions.)

(Basically, I would like to know how large $|S|$ should be to make sure that at least two sequences are identical in $k$ positions.)

Thanks a lot in advance,

Comment: $|S|\ge 2$ is enough for you?

Comment: Downvoted due to ambiguity/ lack of clarity. What does " condition on the number of elements of $S$" mean? And by "two sequences in $S$, " what do you mean? Two subsequences, or... two subsequences each one with consecutive entries? Or...?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Let me clarify: lets say how large the number of elements in $S$ should be so that at least two of the sequences in $S$ have almost $k$ of their elements in common, i.e., there exists two sequences who have the same entries in $k$ positions and this number $k$ is quite large, about half of the sequence length. I hope this is more clear.

Comment: still unclear. what does "almost $k$ of their elements" mean in your comment? Use mathematical notation in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Let me reformulate, what we want is equivalent as the maximal size of subset of $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ on which each pair of elements have at most $k-1$ same digits.

I think youem is right in the case $n \geqslant 3(k-1)$, if you have at least 3 elements in $S = \{u,v,w, \dots \}$, there are $n-k+1$ different integers $i $ such that $u_i \neq v_i$. Necessarily we have for those $i$'s $w_i \in \{ u_i, v_i\} = \mathbb{F}_2$. Let us say that we have $r<k$ indexes on which $w$ takes the values of $u$ and $s<k$ on which it takes the value of $v$. We have $r + s = n-k+1 \leqslant 2k-2$ so $n \leqslant 3(k-1)$. So in this particular case we have $|S| > 2$ as a condition, maybe it is a hint: the condition may involve the binomial coefficient $\binom{3k -4}{n}$.

If you check some references about correcting codes, you might find what you want (hamming distance with distance k or k-1).

Comment: Thank you very much Jules! Your answer is highly insightful. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: You’re welcome, after a few iteration, my conjecture of the binomial coefficient may be wrong, I think it has an “entire part” (not sure about the vocabulary but it is the closest integer smaller than x).